# trying to limit login attempts but query not returning result

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using the following code to lock out users to a limit of `SECURITY_FAIL_300` attempts every 5 min or `SECURITY_FAIL_5` attempts every 5 seconds.  The code successfuly stops the user from making to many attempts(other code adds entries on failed attempt).  However the $timeLimit value always returns 0.

The query returns integer values if I try it in php my admin

database table contains only 2 coloumns.  `ip` which is a varchar(255) and `time` which is a time stamp.

```
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    //setup queries
    $query="select TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),`time`)) from `accessattempts` where `ip`=? AND `time` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL ? SECOND) ORDER BY `time` ASC";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("si",$ip,$limit);
    $stmt->bind_result($timeLeft);

    //see if gone past attemp limits
    $limitsTime=array(300,5);
    $limitsQuantity=array(SECURITY_FAIL_300,SECURITY_FAIL_5);
    $maxRemaining=0;
    for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
        //what limits are we looking for
        $limit=$limitsTime[$i];
        $max=$limitsQuantity[$i];

        //look up how many times they tried
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
        if ($num_rows>$max) {
            //get number of seconds left
            $result->fetch_assoc();
            $remaining=$limit-$timeLeft;

            //see if it is more then other timeouts
            if ($remaining>$maxRemaining) $maxRemaining=$remaining;
        }
    }
    if ($maxRemaining>0) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'success'   => false,
            'reason'    => 'To many attempts.  Locked out for: ' . $maxRemaining . ' seconds'
        ));die();   
    }
    $stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

For your ip is varchar so you should use 'like' instead of '='. Try:
"select TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),`time`)) from `accessattempts` where `ip` like ? AND `time` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL ? SECOND) ORDER BY `time` ASC"

Comment: nope.  also if this was the problem `$num_rows = $result->num_rows;` wouldn't return the correct number of rows.

Comment: I did try it just in case.  As I understand = requires exact match where like allows for while cards to be used in search